# style table with foreach loop

Tags: php, css

I have a table with 8 columns and then a foreach loop running to display all the content in the table. 
I would like to style the table with a scroll bar so the header stays sticky but if I add  all the content only shows under the header for the first column (date). 
How do I add style for the  of the table and at the same time make sure the content is showing in the correct columns?

```
<table id="email_subscription">
<thead>
 <tr>
<th>Date</th>
<th>c1</th> 
<th>c2</th>
<th>c3</th>
<th>c4</th>
<th>c5</th>
<th>Total New</th>
<th>All Contacts</th>
</tr>
</thread>
<tbody>
<?php 

foreach($values as $v_date){
$date = $v_date->DATE; 
$count = $wpdb->get_results($wpdb->prepare(
" SELECT DISTINCT `date`.... ",

echo '<tr class="row_main">';
        echo '<td>' . $date . '</td>';

foreach($count as $counts){
  $val1 =  $counts->c1;
  $val2 = $counts->c2;
  $val3 = $counts->c3;
  $val3a = $counts->c4;
  $val3b = $counts->c5;
  $val9 = $counts->all_contacts;

        echo '<td>' . $val1 . '</td>'; 
        echo '<td>' . $val2 . '</td>';
        echo '<td>' . $val3 . '</td>';
        echo '<td>' . $val3a . '</td>'; 
        echo '<td>' . $val3b . '</td>';   
        echo '<td>' . $val7 . '</td>'; 
        echo '<td>' . $val9 . '</td>';
        echo '</tr>';
    }     
}
 ?>   
</tbody>
</table>
```

It seems display:block; is causing the issue. But how else do I add the scroll?

```
tbody{
   display: block;
   overflow-y:auto;
   overflow-x: hidden;
   height: 100px;
   width: 100%;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think, you should move  outside the second foreach-loop to complete one row:

```
foreach($count as $counts){
  $val1 =  $counts->c1;
  $val2 = $counts->c2;
  $val3 = $counts->c3;
  $val3a = $counts->c4;
  $val3b = $counts->c5;
  $val9 = $counts->all_contacts;

        echo '<td>' . $val1 . '</td>'; 
        echo '<td>' . $val2 . '</td>';
        echo '<td>' . $val3 . '</td>';
        echo '<td>' . $val3a . '</td>'; 
        echo '<td>' . $val3b . '</td>';   
        echo '<td>' . $val7 . '</td>'; 
        echo '<td>' . $val9 . '</td>';
    }     
    echo '</tr>';
}
```

Comment: this doesn't seem to help.